# Querying mongoid for value in attribute array

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I need to search within Mongoid objects that have array attributes. Here are the relevant objects:

```
class Author
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String

class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :authors, type: Array
```

I can see that at least one book has a given author:

```
Book.all.sample.authors
=> [BSON::ObjectId('5363c73a4d61635257805e00'),
 BSON::ObjectId('5363c73a4d61635257835e00'),
 BSON::ObjectId('5363c73a4d61635257c75e00'),
 BSON::ObjectId('5363c73b4d616352574a5f00')]
```

But I'm unable to find books that have that author.

```
Book.where(authors: '5363c73a4d61635257805e00').first
=> nil
```

I've tried the solution listed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoid/csNOcugYH0U but it didn't work for me:

```
Book.any_in(:author => ["5363c73b4d616352574a5f00"]).first
=> nil
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas? I'd prefer to use Mongoid Origin commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This output:

```
Book.all.sample.authors
=> [BSON::ObjectId('5363c73a4d61635257805e00'),
 BSON::ObjectId('5363c73a4d61635257835e00'),
 BSON::ObjectId('5363c73a4d61635257c75e00'),
 BSON::ObjectId('5363c73b4d616352574a5f00')]
```

tells us that `authors` contains `BSON::ObjectId`s. ObjectIds are often presented as Strings and sometimes you can use a String instead of a full blown ObjectId (such as with `Model.find`) but they're still not Strings. You are searching the array for a *String*:

```
Book.where(authors: '5363c73a4d61635257805e00')
```

but `'5363c73a4d61635257805e00'` and `ObjectId('5363c73a4d61635257805e00')` are not the same thing inside MongoDB. You need to search for the right thing:

```
Book.where(authors: BSON::ObjectId('5363c73a4d61635257805e00'))
```

You might want to monkey patch a `to_bson_id` method into various places. Something like this:

```
class String
  def to_bson_id
    BSON::ObjectId.from_string(self)
  end
end

module Mongoid
  module Document
    def to_bson_id
      id
    end
  end
end

module BSON
  class ObjectId
    def to_bson_id
      self
    end
  end
end

class NilClass
  def to_bson_id
    self
  end
end
```

Should do the trick. Then you can say things like:

```
Book.where(authors: '5363c73a4d61635257805e00'.to_bson_id)
Book.where(authors: some_string_or_object_id.to_bson_id)
```

and The Right Thing happens.

You might want to rename `authors` to `author_ids` to make its nature a little clearer.

Comment: Thanks mu! I've used so many of your answers in the past. I ultimately needed to use the BSON::ObjectId.from_string(self), and I've updated your code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the `from_string` fix, I've been using Mongoid/Moped for awhile.